# Why (false==0) is TRUE?

Tags: php

I just `var_dump(false==0)` it outputs `bool(true)`   Why `false== 0` is true.I know `true==1` is true Because  if i  `echo true;` It will output `1` so numeric value of true is `1`,    But numeric value of false is not `0`, because when i `echo false;`  It display nothing(empty), So how can false has same value as `0` AS we know `==` operator compares the values , if they same it will return true, and if their values is not same it will return false , so in the case of `false==0`  It should be false.  Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is
>   converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
>   forth between boolean and string values.

So both `false == ""` and `false == 0` are true. Remember, `"0"` is not the same as `0`.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question , you are saying `false==0` is true , I know this, but i am asking why ? false value is converted into "" not into 0

Comment: @beginner read what I wrote again. 0 is the same as "". Just a string or an int representation.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a check here.

[PHP Type Comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

In short, `==` is the **loose comparison operator** which invokes type conversion before comparison. Maybe you should use the **strict comparison operator** `===` instead.

The same story goes in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`false` has the the same value as `0`, it is just another way of writing it 
So, `false == 0` will be the same thing as saying

`0 == 0`
which returns `true` because `0 = 0`

Comment: I understand false value is just  0 , the conception is that false don't `echo  false` dont prints out  `0` so  question is why   `echo false` don't print 0